# Двоеточие или тире: "Был в папке еще один документ — отчет об операции на планете"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

> Во-вторых, был в папке еще один документ — отчет об операции на планете.

В книге и в сборнике упражнений в этом предловении стоит тире. Если смотреть по правилу, то здесь можно вставить "а именно", и должно быть двоеточие. Какой вариант правильный?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Во-вторых, был в папке еще один **документ — отчет об операции на планете.***

Я думаю, что в этом предложении "работает" следующее правило:
при обособлении приложений используется тире, если перед приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить *а именно* (особенно **если приложение стоит в конце предложения, имеет зависимые слова** и внутри него уже есть знаки препинания).
[Обособление приложений](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/718-242_obosoblenie_prilozhenii.html)

*В отношениях с посторонними он требовал **одного – сохранения приличия*** (Герцен).
*В дальнем углу светилось желтое **пятно – огонь в окне квартиры Серафимы, пристроенной к стене конюшни*** (Горький).

Answer (score 1):

Если смотреть по правилу, то здесь можно вставить "а именно", и должно быть **ТИРЕ**:

> [§ 19. Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111)
>   10. При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется тире:
>   1) если перед приложением можно вставить слова **а именно** (без изменения смысла): В дальнем углу светилось жёлтое пятно — огонь квартиры Серафимы (Ж. Г.); Она зарисовала древние светильники с гербом города Ольвии — орлом, парящим над дельфинами (Пауст.); На суховатом лице Нечаева, с мягким мальчишеским лбом, остались следы ожогов — два белых незагорающих пятна (Н. Чук.);